# Access to images on WP7 Silverlight App project

Tags: c#, windows-phone-7

In my project in WP7 App / Silverlight I got some images that I would like to access on running WP7 app. Is that possible?

I mean - for example.

I am creating folder MyImages into my project.
I put there few .png, example 1.png, 2.png etc.

I run application (compile etc)

I am able to modify those files? For example save something different to

MyImages/1.png

Some kind of overwrite this file?

---------------------------- ADDED

```
using (IsolatedStorageFile myIsolatedStorage = IsolatedStorageFile.GetUserStoreForApplication())
            {
                if (myIsolatedStorage.FileExists(fileName))
                {
                    myIsolatedStorage.DeleteFile(fileName);
                }

                IsolatedStorageFileStream fileStream = myIsolatedStorage.CreateFile(fileName);
                BitmapImage bitmap = new BitmapImage();
                bitmap.SetSource(imageStream);

                WriteableBitmap wb = new WriteableBitmap(bitmap);
                wb.SaveJpeg(fileStream, wb.PixelWidth, wb.PixelHeight, 0, 85);

                MessageBox.Show(imageStream.ToString());

                fileStream.Close();
            }
```

Answer (score 0):

yes you can [here](http://blogs.microsoft.co.il/blogs/tomershamam/archive/2010/10/12/saving-and-loading-captured-image-to-and-from-wp7-isolated-storage.aspx) is a good article to begin

Comment: I read something about IsolatedStorage.

But how exactly I can modify MyImages/1.png? (I added something to question, I save bitmap, but still it won't overwrite MyImages/1.bmp etc. How to create a full URI with foldername/filename.png